# Using a lambda in the :select option of a has_one relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, arel

I want to select additional fields in a query of a `has_one` relationship in `ActiveRecord`.

The problem is: The content of the select query must be evaluated every time the select query is fired, because I get the value of the additional field of a stored procedure and I need to pass a parameter during runtime.

I would imagine it to work somehow like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :profile, :select => lambda { "SELECT profiles.*, my_stored_procedure(#{Time.now}) as virtual_attribute" }

end
```

I can't use a scope, because I need to prefetch this relation using `includes` on a parent model:

```
User.includes(:profile).find(1,2,3)
```

and also as a second level prefetched model:

```
OtherModel.includes(:user => [ :profile ])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My Solution**

One possible solution I found is to subclass the model and overwrite the `default_scope` which can also take a block. I have tested it and it works as expected!

But it is important to note that this only works in `Rails 3.1`, as `3.0` does **not** accept blocks for the `default_scope` method (they are just ignored).

Here is an example of the models involved:

```
class Other < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :users

end


class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :profile
  has_one :profile_with_relationship

end


class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base  
end


class ProfileWithRelationship < Profile

  set_table_name "profiles"

  default_scope do
    select("'#{Time.now}' as virtual_attribute")
  end

end
```

It now works even with nested includes:

```
Other.includes(:users => :profile_with_relationship).find(1)
```

Will produce:

```
Other Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "others".* FROM "others" WHERE "others"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."other_id" IN (1)
ProfileWithRelationship Load (0.2ms)  SELECT '2011-11-23 11:34:15 +0100' as virtual_attribute, "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."user_id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

In my special case this is fine, as I don't need the values of the stored proc not all the time and can query it now only for the cases I need it.

Hope this helps anyone else. :)